# Linq to sql: Merge child rows into one single entity

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have three tables like so:

**Presets:**

```
ID int PK,
Name nvarchar
```

**Preset_milestone_presets**: (link table)

```
presetId int PK, FK to Preset-table.
milestoneId int PK
```

**Preset_titles_presets**: (link table)

```
presetId int PK, FK to Preset-table.
titleId int PK
```

And a C# Entity like so:

Preset:

```
int[] milestoneIds
int[] titleIds
```

So I'm wondering what the best way, using linq-to-sql, is to create on single entity that have a merged distinct list of `milestoneIds` and `titleIds` that represents multiple presets. (Joined against multiple rows in the Presets table)?

EDIT:
Data examples:

**Prestes**

```
1   "Preset 1"
2   "Preset 2"
```

**Preset_milestone_presets**

```
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   5
2   6
```

**Preset_titles_presets**

```
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   3
2   4
```

Expected result when requesting presets with id 1 and 2 is a single entity with the following arrays:
    milestoneIds: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
    titleIds: { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

Comment: can you share a data sample, please.

Comment: I don't understand. When you have preset 1 then you can access all milestones and titles with a simple for each. `For each m in preset.milestones ...`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want just one. I want a merged entity for preset 1 and preset 2.

Comment: Instead to get a new entity, what you think about to take a new structure that include this data. Perhaps a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). Why do you need a entity?

Comment: Well the storage options is not the problem. The problem is getting the id's I want from the database in the most optimised way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this code help to you:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> result = 
   new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

/*id's */
List<int> ids = new List<int>(new int[] { 1,2 });

/* Tanking Prestes */
var my_presets = 
   (from p in Prestes 
    join i in ids
    on p.id = i
    select p);

/*Taking Milestones*/
my_milestones_ids = 
   (from m in Preset_milestone_presets 
    join p in my_presets
    on m.idPreset = p.id
    select m.id).Distinct().ToList();

/*Taking titles*/
my_titles_ids = 
   (from t in Preset_titles_presets 
    join p in my_presets
    on t.idPreset = p.id
    select t.id).Distinct().ToList();

/* result */
result.Add( "presets_ids", ids);
result.Add( "milestones_ids", my_milestones_ids);
result.Add( "titles_ids", my_titles_ids);
```

If you don't like joins try with:

```
/* Tanking Prestes */
var my_presets = 
   (from p in Prestes 
    where ids.Contains( p.id)
    select p);

/*Taking Milestones*/
my_milestones_ids = 
   (from m in Preset_milestone_presets 
    where my_presets.Contains( m.Preset) 
    select m.id).Distinct().ToList();

/*Taking titles*/
my_titles_ids = 
   (from t in Preset_titles_presets 
    where my_presets.Contains( t.Preset) 
    select t.id).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there no way of doing this in one call?

Comment: I think that the mos elegant way to get this behavior is expand preset with a partial class, something like get_merge_childs_with( ids ). Write a new method in partial class that returns this dictionary. You need help to achieve this?

Comment: @emaz, danihp: Since you have the foreign key constraint, I don't think you need to do the `Contains` check or the join.  Unfortunately you're going to have to query at least twice to get the two sub-tables, and three times if you want to get the master table IDs that don't exist in either sub-table.  There's just no way around this without removing results, as you have two/three distinct sets represented in your DB.